# ML - What are the benefits of transforming variables with long tail?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

What are the obvious benefits of transforming variables with long tail distributions? To extend it more, why the machine learning algorithms will perform better afer such a transformation?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide more context.  Where did you encounter this question?  Why do you think there are benefits?  In what context are you asking?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: (Know [ML](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language))?) (Where benefits are obvious, it should be dispensable to ask - e.g., a spelling checker should catch `afer`)